# Exporting the whole vba code from an ms access application

Tags: file, vba, ms-access, export, directory

I have an ms access Application ( ms access 2013) and I'd like to export all vba code to separate files in a folder

What code can i add to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by separate files? If you mean each module, can you not just right click on each module -> Export and save?

Comment: Or use VBA Extensibility?

Comment: Yes I can do this, but I had more than 100 modules!!

Comment: @Jiminy Cricket I'm beginner in VBA , so what do u mean by  VBA Extensibility ?

Comment: Extensibility is the way in which you modify your code using other code. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx I hope this helps

Comment: @JiminyCricket Exactly I need a procedure that export all vba code to separate files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub ExportVBAComponents()

  Dim wbPath As String
  Dim vbComp As Object
  Dim exportPath As String

  wbPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  For Each vbComp In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    exportPath = wbPath & "\" & vbComp.Name & Format$(Now, "_yyyymmdd_hhnnss")

    Select Case vbComp.Type
        Case 1 ' Standard Module
            exportPath = exportPath & ".bas"
        Case 2 ' UserForm
            exportPath = exportPath & ".frm"
        Case 3 ' Class Module
            exportPath = exportPath & ".cls"
        Case Else ' Anything else
            exportPath = exportPath & ".bas"
    End Select

    On Error Resume Next
    vbComp.Export exportPath
    On Error GoTo 0
  Next

End Sub
```

The code above will export all the VBA components/modules in your `ActiveWorkbook` to the same location as your workbook. It will use the component name as part of the file name and will add a timestamp. Since you have more than 100 modules, you'd better change the export path to include a subfolder to group them all together in one place.

**NOTE:** For this to work, you need to select *Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings...>Macro Settings>Trust access to the VBA project object model*. Otherwise you get some random error in the `For Each` line. You can tick that option off afterwards if you're worried about it.

Comment: it indicates that the variable `ActiveWorkbook` not found!!

Comment: @LamloumiAfif: Ah yes, I tested it with exporting modules from Excel. Not sure what it's called for Access (haven't used it for ages), I'll try to investigate and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks  very much , I'm waiting :)

Comment: @LamloumiAfif: Actually, while searching for it I realised it's already been answered here: [Exporting MS Access Forms and Class / Modules Recursively to text files?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17362688/3593811). Can you please take a look and see if that works for you? It's seems to cover all bases very well.

Comment: should be exporting to `.bas` file extension for `vbCompType = 1`, and to `.frm` file extension for `vbCompType = 3` and `.cls` for `vbCompType = 2`, this way you can also export class modules and forms.

Comment: @DavidZemens: My code was just for standard modules, you are correct. Thank you for your input. The Access-specific SO question I linked in my previous comment is much more comprehensive and can deal with all kinds of Access modules.

Comment: Remember to refer to / Check the **Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility Library** in VBE > Tools > References.

Comment: This doesn't work in ms access. I recieved a compile error

Comment: To get to the VBComponents collection in the Access object model, use `For Each vbComp In VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents`.  This worked for me (and I changed the setting of the path at `wbPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path` to just a constant.)