# Hard Drive Location of Access VBA Modules

Tags: vba, ms-access, module

in Excel, if I want to save my modules created for use across all Excel workbooks, I have the **Personal.xlsb** folder located here,

> C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB.

I can also save the **Personal.xlsb** file on a network drive for safe keeping should my computer corrupt or need re-imaging.

Where oh where is the same file for Access?  Does it exist or do I have to export each module?  My computer was backed up by IT and all of my Access vba modules are gone for every database I have.

Thanx!

Comment: I keep trying to add, "Hi," to the beginning of that post, but it won't save the edit.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as [@stewart Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1649060/stewart-ross) said, there is no equivalent of the personal.xlsb file in Access. But in the VBA editor in an Access file, you can select a reference to your own "master Database". For example, my "master database" with cool and useful subs and functions is Masterdatabase.accdb and I got another database called MyNewdatabase.accdb. I open VBA editor, references, and I lookp up for my masterdatabase.accdb and mark it as a reference library, and now all code I designed in my "master database" is available in the new database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of the personal.xlsb file in Access. All modules are stored within the .accdb / .mdb database itself. You can export all modules and store them as text files using VBA code, as this SO answer amongst others shows:

[Exporting the whole vba code from an ms access application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780363/exporting-the-whole-vba-code-from-an-ms-access-application)

Comment: Thanx for the response.  That is helpful.  If it is in the database itself, do you know why the database is on a network drive, but the modules are now gone after the c:/ drive was re-imaged?  There must be something local keeping the modules within the database.

Comment: Also, what does "SO" mean?

Comment: SO is Stack Overflow! Access applications are often split into separate back-end tables that sit on a network, and a front-end application that is on your local drive. I suspect that to be the case for you. The VBA modules would be in the C-drive front-end database, not the tables-only back end.