# VBA Access export code module to folder

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to get Access VBA to copy one of its modules out to a folder - I have looked at the other threads / google and no joy - what do you think? Code below

```
Sub copy_out_module()
    Set appAccess = New Access.Application 
    Set dbsCurr = appAccess.CurrentProject

    Const ModulePath As String = "C:\Users\Sjohn\Documents\Components\"

    dbsCurr.Item("Module2").Export ModulePath
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting MS Access Forms and Class / Modules Recursively to text files?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948215/exporting-ms-access-forms-and-class-modules-recursively-to-text-files

Answer (score 2):

Your last line `dbsCurr.Item("Module2").Export ModulePath` can't run (Err. 438 Object can't admit property or method).

You can check this thread on StackOverflow: [Export All Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948215/exporting-ms-access-forms-and-class-modules-recursively-to-text-files).

I those sample code simple remmember to add the library Visual Basic for Application Extensibility. All code are perfect and only i add two lines for DIM some vars.

```html
Sub ExportAllCode()
Dim c As Object
Dim sfx As String

For Each c In Application.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents
Select Case c.Type
    Case vbext_ct_ClassModule, vbext_ct_Document
        sfx = ".cls"
    Case vbext_ct_MSForm
        sfx = ".frm"
    Case vbext_ct_StdModule
        sfx = ".bas"
    Case Else
        sfx = ""
End Select
If sfx <> "" Then
    c.Export _
        Filename:=CurrentProject.Path & "\" & _
        c.Name & sfx
End If
Next c

End Sub
```