# Execute VBA code on save in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to write a VBA script to export all of the VBA code in a given file to plaintext files for version control. I've already solved that part thanks to a [bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27989015/1354930)
[of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24162356/1354930)
[answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17362688/1354930)
and 
[google](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm)
[results](https://gist.github.com/steve-jansen/7589478)
.

However, I'm now looking to automate this process for **MS Access**. I've done it successfully in Excel by putting code in the [`ThisWorkbook` module which runs on the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365756/1354930).

However, I've been unable to find any analog to `ThisWorkbook` in MS Access.

So the question is:

**How can I execute VBA on the `BeforeSave` event in Access?**

I'd like this to run on either a save in MS Access or a save in the VBA Editor.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think access have a `beforeSave` event at all. after all all data are always imediatly writen to the disk anyway.

Comment: Are you asking about an event which fires when VBA code changes are saved?

Comment: You might want to give a glance to https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck. They are working on a solution with git. Hopefully the release of 2.0 is finished soon.

Comment: @HansUp Yes, that's correct. To litelite: Yes, that's what I thought the case was. To INOPIAE: Thanks for the info, I'll check it out.