# Importing a module into access programmatically from a *.cls or similar file

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

If you open Microsoft Access, then open the visual basic window so you can see the list of modules and code in your Access project.  You can drag a text-based file (txt, cls, bas, etc) from windows explorer and drop it into your module folder.

This drag and drop action will import the code in the text-based file into your project and prompt you to save it (with the default name being the name of the file you dropped.

Is there a way to do this programmatically using VBA? It seems like a simple task that should have a simple solution, but I've been researching for days and can't seem to find a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the command `LoadFromText` to use.

Usage:

```
LoadFromText acModule, "NameOfObject", "FileName"
```

Comment: Since `LoadFromText` is undocumented, you should probably give some details of how to use it.

Comment: Well, added, though IntelliSense tells it all.

Comment: This worked perfectly and was incredibly simple. Thank you!

Comment: In my experience, this works fine with normal modules, but fails with class modules, since it imports them as if they were normal modules.

Comment: Interestingly, you can also export Tables, Querys and Forms with SaveAsText, then load them with LoadFromText, so you can keep your whole Access application into a version control repository.

Comment: @Gustav: Did you use it with a Class module or a normal module? In Access 2013 it fails with Class modules, maybe they corrected it in Access 2016. Please make sure that the Application compiles correctly and that the imported modules appear as Class modules. You need to export the Class module previously. I am interested in your results.

Comment: I don't export and import. That may not work. It is `SaveAsText` and `LoadFromText`. The two commands are those used for repository transport. Can't tell for 2013 as I don't have it installed, but for 2016 it works - at least here.

Comment: @Gustav: Yeah, I understand, it's only a matter of terminology. But, please, can you explicitly confirm that you have saved a Class module, not a regular one with SaveAsText? And, again, that when you load it with LoadFromText it gets created as a Class module and not as a regular one? Please, give it a try before answering to make sure. I assume that you are used to Class modules, are you? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that. Two forms, two small class modules, save, and then load from a new, empty database. Worked right away.

Comment: Access 2010 and 2013 here, all is working fine. Forms, classes, modules.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `VBComponents.Import` method from the VBE object model.  See the *Import Method (VBA Add-In Object Model)* topic in Access' help system for details.

This sample code imported *modImportMe.bas* from the folder where my database is stored.

```vb
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strProject As String

strFile = "modImportMe.bas"
strPath = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & strFile
Debug.Print strPath
If Len(Dir(strPath)) > 0 Then
    'VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import strPath
    VBE.VBProjects("Database2").VBComponents.Import strPath
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCompileAndSaveAllModules
Else
    MsgBox "File not found: " & strPath, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Oops!"
End If
```

Note this database actually contains only one `VBProject`, so I could have referenced it with `VBE.ActiveVBProject`.  However if yours includes more than one `VBProject`, it's safer to refer to it by name, and `VBProjects("<Name>")` should work even when there is only one.

Comment: I think this will work with some tweaking. I got it to import some code into my project, but it put it into a file i was referencing instead of the current accdb. which was weird to begin with. Then it started giving me errors.

So I think with a little work, this also would have been a viable solution, so for that, I thank you, but for simplicity reasons, I went with Gustav for my answer. Perhaps someone else will find yours as a better alternative.

Comment: This is the right way to go, specially if you have class modules in your code. I usually import from the same application, so, I use Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import "filename"