# how to open the vba form in external application like notepad and notead++

Tags: vba

I want to know how to read the ms access form (vba form) via external application 
like (notepad,notepad++).

In vb6 application can be able to read the [control name],[code] in the external application (notepad,notepad++).
but, there is no option for to do the same operation in the ms access forms.

when i open the form in the database i can ,but not in the notepad and notepad++.

It is possible or not (or) is there any other way to do this action.

Comment: I guess when you open the form via notepad you see only random gibberish? If so, they are in binary form and you can only open them using dedicated software.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the form code that is shown in the VBA editor.  In VB and C# you can view the code that actually creates the control objects and initialises them (I think it is this that you are referring to).  You can't see this code in Access / VBA.

If you want to edit the code in Notepad++ simply copy and paste it from the VBA code editor (which is shown when you press ALT+F11).

PS. I use a access addin called OASIS-SVN that can export all object definitions as text files, I probably does it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948215/exporting-ms-access-forms-and-class-modules-recursively-to-text-files)

Comment: Did you find the above useful?  If so please flag as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit VBA projects files outside from VBE, you first need to Export them (using Right-click->Export a file) and save them somewhere.
Then you'll be able to open them with notepad(++).

Don't forget to Import them back into your VBA Project after editing.