# The system cannot find the file specified after running 20 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I am getting this exception for process.start().  The system cannot find the file specified.  But this happens after the function correctly starts and runs the program for 20 seconds.  It seems like the process is still going when it throws this exception?  This is a MS Access program an .mdb file I'm running.

```
string mdbPath = @"P:\MyProgram.mdb"
string parameterString = "";
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(mdbPath, parameterString);
var procExited = proc.WaitForExit(2400000);
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502294/trying-to-open-an-access-database-using-process-start-database-not-attached

Comment: Yes I think the error is coming from the mdb.

Comment: Still getting this issue is it due to calling the mdb while it is still running? because I'm calling it multiple times.